# Emacs 24 with prelude. .emacs conflict?

Tags: c++, emacs

I installed [emacs prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude). I use it to edit in C++ mainly. I have most of the things I would want for editing, but I am missing one.

I want to use gnu global, so I installed the package via `M-x list-packages`. I want to activate it by default for c++ files. I have 2 problems:

1. Before using prelude, I would set up everything in `${HOME}/.emacs` file, but it seems that prelude uses `${HOME}/.emacs.d/init.el`. If I create a .emacs file, all prelude configuration will disappear. How can I preserve it? Maybe I should use a `.emacs` file still for my personal configuration and load from there init.el?
2. I want to enable gnu global when I open a c++ file by default, but I don't know wether I have to set up a hook or what lisp variable/function to use for that, and in which file I should do it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, you are already answering yourself :-).  Just do a `(load "path-to-your-prelude-init-pile") in your .emacs.  Emacs looks first for .emacs, then for ${HOME}/.emacs.d/init.el if the former is not found.

For 2,  Put something like this in your config file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
    (lambda ()
       (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode)
         (ggtags-mode 1))))
```

Comment: Ad 2) You should replace `'c-mode` with `major-mode`, currently it will always be nil.